# Azure DevOps YAML Variables Evaluation Order

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an issue with a variable evaluating to Null on a Condition.

This is the pipeline:

I have a variable template that is pulled in by the main yml file:

```yaml
variables:
  - ${{ if startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/feature/') }}:
    - name: is_sandbox
      value: true

  - ${{ if eq(variables['system.pullRequest.targetBranch'], 'refs/heads/master') }}:
    - name: is_sandbox
      value: true
    - name: bob
      value: a
```

Note that is_sandbox is not set anywhere else.

I then have a condition on job:

```yaml
condition: or (eq(variables.is_sandbox, true), eq(variables.bob, 'a'))
```

But this fails to evaluate. In the log is see:

```
system.pullRequest.targetBranch : refs/heads/master

and:

Expanded: or(eq(Null, True), eq(Null, 'a'))
Result: False
```

So it appears that the variables template has not set correctly. Why would that be?

Comment: Can you provide the scoping of your variable?  `is_sandbox` is that being set at pipeline, stage, job?

Comment: @DreadedFrost - it's at the Stage. I believe that two pre-defined variables are evaluating to Null when it runs. I would have thought these should be available anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Stage variables will only be available to activities within the stage.  This is beneficial when reusing variables with different values across different stages.  Think potentially stage is tied to an environment and the environment values are different so thus can pass in different variables at the stage level.

I believe you are looking to define these at the [root level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass) so variable values will be available to anything in the pipelines unless it is overwritten by a lower level scope.

Comment: The job which the condition is on is in the same Stage. Surely that should inherit?

Comment: It should.  It sounds like the path to the template file containing the variables might be incorrect.

Comment: The path must be correct because if I take out the if block the variables get set. I'm completely at a loss. A days of my life has been spent on this. I can't understand how debugging this can be so hard!

Comment: Can you share more of your YAML?

Comment: Argh - according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services certain variables are not available in templates (last column on the tables). Including this one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Learn something new everyday! One option might consider is to default the variables values at the root and then load the variable file at the stage thus overwriting it.....or store  two variable files one for each condition and use something else to determine which one to load.